# What do I need for a Webpage if I would use Scala + MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, nosql

I have to make a small project and I have to use a nosql db and a language which runs on the JVM. So i thought: Scala and MongoDB

I think that will be fine, except you guys say "Dont use scala with any nosql db it runs bad, use java!". The only problem is that i need a small web gui for this all. Just some simple things like a button and a textbox to fill up the database and later some cool (maybe colored) output of some datas. So no "big-hyper-flash-html5-super-website".

What do I have for options? I heard about the Lift Framework for Scala. Im sure its great, but i never used it. Is it worth to use it? Are there some easy "all-in-one-pack" tools? I found this: http://www.getslimstack.net/ It would make my life easier, but its only for windows, I need something on linux.

Or should I use Java (Java EE) and that would make everything easier, because Lift and other stuff is too complicated? The most important thing is that I use a nosql db.

Comment: Just to note - there is special mongodb toolkit for scala called [Casbah](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.1.5.0/). It has some scala goodies (like __loan pattern__)

Answer (score 4):

Try [Scalatra](http://www.scalatra.org/)
It's simple and clear. Moreover, since it uses sbt, that's easy to integrate any  mongodb library, such as Casbah or lift-mongo-record.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [circumflex](http://circumflex.ru/) for creating web applications, connecting to DB, rendering [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html) templates and other useful tools. There is a [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/circumflex-scala) and [github repo](https://github.com/inca/circumflex) where you can find some answers.

And how about [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)? it is not so bad at all. AFAIK there is only restriction, that only 1 JVM can connect to it at the same time.